# how to save qty_available in databse for showing it on each product pos odoo?

Tags: odoo, pos

I want to save quantity available (qty_available) field in product_template model in database for each product. How can i do this?

I want to show available quantity on each product in pos. So i need qty_available how can i do this?

```
qty_available = fields.Float(
        'Quantity On Hand', compute='_compute_quantities', search='_search_qty_available',
        digits=dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure'),
        help="Current quantity of products.\n"
             "In a context with a single Stock Location, this includes "
             "goods stored at this Location, or any of its children.\n"
             "In a context with a single Warehouse, this includes "
             "goods stored in the Stock Location of this Warehouse, or any "
             "of its children.\n"
             "stored in the Stock Location of the Warehouse of this Shop, "
             "or any of its children.\n"
             "Otherwise, this includes goods stored in any Stock Location "
             "with 'internal' type.")
```

This field in defined in stock.
How to make it available in product_template or in pos module for using it?

Comment: That isn't so easy, because this fields computation depends heavily on context (which warehouse, which location(s), and so on). That is the reason why it is not stored in db.

Comment: For my case their is no warehouse. i am newly learner just working in my local. @CZoellne

Comment: They are stored anywhere in local? @CZoellne

Comment: No they aren't stored anywhere. This field is completely computed and not stored in database.

Comment: can i acces these value using product.id ?

Comment: How they are calculated?

Comment: You really have to look into the code and understand a bit more here. I can't help you by understanding special thinks in Odoo like the stock module.

Comment: Okay i do this. thanxx @CZoellner